# Conquering the Physics GRE Electron spins want to be anti-aligned with the magnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-spin

in Conquering the Physics GRE, there’s an paragraph that says

> Physically, the electron spin wants to be anti-aligned with the magnetic field since this is energetically favorable (section 5.7.4)

if the book is speaking generally, isn’t this just wrong since (I know this is classical) $U = -\mu \cdot B$ and so will be minimized when the dipole and field are aligned?

Comment: Do you understand how $\vec\mu$ and $\vec S$ are related?